# How to enable log rotation in envoy file based logging?

Tags: api-gateway, envoyproxy

I am using envoy as api gateway. For logging, I am using a file-based logging approach (schema - type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog).

The logs are accumulated in a file but how does log rollover work here? Will the log file get bigger and bigger every day?

Answer (score 2):

There is no log rotation available out-of-the-box with Envoy (see [issue #1109](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/1109)).

However, you can use a tool like [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to handle your access logs file rotation. The following config can be used to rotate logs daily and keep 7 days of logs:

```
/var/log/envoy/access.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    compress
    notifempty
    nocreate
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
}
```

Just put that config in a file named `/etc/logrotate.d/envoy`, and check that `logrotate` is run daily (`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`).

You can test this using a container:

```
FROM    envoyproxy/envoy:v1.22.2

RUN     apt update && apt install -y logrotate

RUN     install -d -m 0755 -o envoy -g envoy /var/log/envoy

# logrotate_envoy.conf is logrotate config file
COPY    logrotate_envoy.conf /etc/logrotate.d/envoy
```

And use this envoy config:

```yaml
access_log:
- name: envoy.access_loggers.file
  typed_config:
    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
    path: /var/log/envoy/access.log
```

Comment: I learned about this approach from the envoy GitHub page. Bit surprising why it's not supported by the envoy directly. Thanks for answering